# Escaping characters in Ruby Shell

Tags: ruby, git, bash, shell, awk

I have a bash command:

```
git log --numstat --pretty="%H" -1 | awk 'NF==3 {plus+=$1; minus+=$2} END {printf("+%d, -%d\n", plus, minus)}'
```

I want to assign this command as a string variable and process the output using `exec(stringname)` method.

The string command breaks at `"+%d, -%d\n"`. Is there a way I can escape these special characters?

Comment: `exec` replaces your Ruby process with the given command, i.e. you can't process its output.

Comment: have you tried heredoc?

Comment: Instead of using `awk`, why not just rewrite that in Ruby? [`popen3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3) can give you output from any given command, like `git`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to quote something that has quotes in it already, use the `%q` method:

```
command = %q[git log --numstat --pretty="%H" -1 | awk 'NF==3 {plus+=$1; minus+=$2} END {printf("+%d, -%d\n", plus, minus)}']
```

Doing all of this in Ruby gives you a lot more control:

```
require 'open3'

Open3.popen3('git', 'log', '--numstat', '--pretty="%H"', '-1') do |stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr|
  stdout.each_line do |line|
    if (line.match(/\A(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(.*)/))
      puts '+%d, -%d' % [ $1, $2 ]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Open3 FTW. How many entries are there in the CERT database because people messed up the shell quoting while trying to use backticks, `system`, and friends?

Comment: @muistooshort Indeed. In many cases `system` is hardly better than `eval`. Too few actually use `shellescape`.